# Indexing text files in java

Tags: java, text, indexing

I have a set of text files providing informations that are parsed, analysed and allow building a model. Sometime, the user of this model wants to know which part of a text file was used to generate a given model item.

For that I am thinking of keeping track of the range of lines (or bytes) ids to be able to read the appropriate text part once required.

My question is: I wonder if it their exists any java Reader able to read a file by using a start and stop line (or byte) id instead of reading the file from the begining and counting the lines (bytes)?

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know exactly amount of bytes, that should be skipped, you can use seek method method of [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Comment: Plus there is clearly no way to be able to specify the line offset AND not need to read sequentially from the top.

Answer (score 2):

To read from the certain byte - [SeekableByteChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html). Of cause, there aren't any Readers able to start from the line id - because positions of line separators are unknown.

Comment: It looks great, but unfortunately the 1.7 requirement is bad for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InputStream.mark()` and `InputStream.skip()` to navigate to concrete position into the file.

But are you sure you really have to implement this yourself? Take a look on [Lucine](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) - the indexing service that probably will help you.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Lucene for this task as there is no text search involved, it's just about indexing (as in "array index") into a known file.

Comment: I know just a little about Lucene, and yes, I think it is a little too much, since we are not planing to search, but only to retrieve text slices.